# How do I use hooks to rerender after a condition has changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a page where i want it to show one component if a user is logged in, if not logged in, it shows the login component.

I am trying to make it such that after login, test the same condition and automatically change state to the component that requires authentication.

Right now I have it where, it shows me the login page. After I login if I click refresh, it still stays on the login page, but if I go to another page, and come back, it works. How do I make it always check if logged in?

I am trying to use hook `useEffect`, but I am not achieving this.

The solution doesn't have to be hooks, could be anything, I just thought maybe hooks was the way to solve this issue.

```
const Properties = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  console.log(user);

  useEffect(() => {
    setUser(auth.currentUser);
  }, [auth.currentUser]);

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Add Property</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="web dev" />
      </Head>
      <h1>Add Property</h1>
      <p>Welcome to the add Property new</p>

      {user ? <AddProperty /> : <Login />}
    </>
  );
};

export default Properties;
```

Here is the login component (*i excluded the jsx and unnecessary bits*).

```
onSubmit: (values) => {
  console.log("onSubmit", values);
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, values.email, values.password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      const user = userCredential.user;
      console.log("user logger in");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
    });
  },
});
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `auth` or `auth.currentUser` as a dependency of your `useEffect`?

Comment: yes, it doesnt change the page to the other component though

Comment: when i do that, if i refresh the page, the condition is tested again. But i dont want to have to refresh the page

Comment: where does auth come from?

Comment: its coming from another component, im using firebase authenticate, i imported it

Comment: Please add Login component here

Comment: as a dependency to the hook ? or you want to see the code ?

Comment: How do you declare and export/import auth? that's the key here.

Comment: import { auth } from "../../components/firebase";

Comment: That code works as expected. The issue `[auth.currentuser]` isn't detecting a change, and thus `setUser` isn't being called. We need more information to debug. Does your `Login` component handle communicating with Firebase for authentication?

Comment: yes, i will edit the question and add it

Comment: You need to show exactly where your `Properties` component is receiving the `auth` object. If it's not a prop, in the component itself, then the `Properties` component will not see when its value changes until something else inside it causes a re-render.